# Prove $f(x)=x^2+3x$ is Continuous at $x=a$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, solution-verification, epsilon-delta

I am attempting to give a $\delta,\epsilon$ proof that the following function, $f(x)=x^2+3x$ is continuous at $x=a$, where $a$ is any real number. I have the following:

> Given any $\epsilon > 0$, find a $\delta > 0$ such that if $|x-a|<\delta$ then $|(x^2+3x)-((a^2)+3a)|<\epsilon\\ \\$
> $\text{We have that:}\\ \\
> \quad\quad \begin{align}|(x^2+3x)-((a^2)+3a)| &= |x-a||x+a|+3|x-a| <\epsilon\\
> &=|x-a||x+a+3| <\epsilon \end{align}\\$
> $\text{Attempt to Bound $|x+a+3|$: Let $\delta \leq 1$}\\ \\
> \quad\quad \begin{align} &\Rightarrow |x-a|<1\\
> &\Rightarrow -1 <x-a<1\\
> &\Rightarrow a-1<x<a+1 ;\text{add $a+3$ in order to obtain $x+a+3$}\\ 
> &\Rightarrow 2a+2<x+a+3<2a+4\\\end{align}$

The issue seems to be my attempt to bound $|x+a+3|$ because I am supposed to reach the following:

> $\begin{align}|(x^2+3x)-((a^2)+3a)| &= |x-a||x+a|+3|x-a| <\epsilon\\
> &=|x-a||x+a+3|< \epsilon\\
> &=|x-a|*(2|a|+3)< \epsilon\\
> &=|x-a|< \frac{\epsilon}{2|a|+3}\\ \\
> &\text{Choose $\delta=min(1,\frac{\epsilon}{2|a|+3})$} \end{align}\\$

I am not exactly sure how we arrive at $2|a|+3$. An idea that I have is if $2a+2<x+a+3<2a+4$, and $a$ is a real number, then $2a+3$ is in between $2a+2$ and $2a+4$.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: $x$ is very close to $a$ so $|x + a + 3|$ is very close to $|2a + 3|$.   We want to put this in some *absolute* bound.  If $a \ge 0$ this is fine.  $|2a + 3|=2a+3 \le 2|a| + 3$.  If $-\frac 32 \le a<0$ then $|2a+3|=3-2|a|$ That's a different value but $3-2|a| < 3 < 2|a|+3$ so we can use the same bound (no harm in choosing a bound too big). And if $a <-\frac 23$ then $|2a +3| = 2|a|-3$.  But we *still* have $2|a|-3< 2|a| < 2|a|+3$.  so for all cases $2|a|+3$ is a safe and acceptable bound that *universally* works.

Comment: @fleablood Thank you! Just to clarify, are $a \geq 0$, $\frac{-3}{2} \leq a < 0$, and $a < \frac{-3}{2}$, arbitrary cases to show that the bound $2|a|+3$ will work?

Comment: Well, not "arbitrary" .... This basically boils down to "How big can $|M + N|$ be in terms of $|M|$ and $|N|$.  If $M$ and $N$ are the  same sign then $|M+N| = |M|+|N|$ and thats a fine bound.  BUt if $M$ and $N$ are opposite signs then $|M+N| = ||M| -|N||$.  But that's okay because $-|M| - |N| \le |M| - |N| \le |M| + |N|$ so $||M|-|N|| \le |M| + |N|$ in any event whether $M,N$ are pos,neg or mixed we will *always* have $|M + N| \le |M| + |N|$  so we can use that as a bound.  If $a > 0$ then we'd just use $2a + 3$.  But if $a < 0$ we.... well $2|a| +3$ will *still* work.

Answer (score 1):

Use the sequential criterion for continuity at $a$. Let $(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ be a real sequence with limit $a$. Now, it suffices to show $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(a_n)=f(a)$.
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}f(a_n)=\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n(a_n+3)=\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n\cdot\lim_{n\to\infty}(a_n+3)=a(a+3)=f(a)$$